# Can I have dynamic named routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pages controller in which I support 3 static pages (for example : aboutus, faq and home). I don't have any actions inside the controller, just the appropriate views so adding new pages will be easy.

I used the default route : 
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

and can now access my pages through : 'http://localhost:3000/pages/faq' (or any other page)

I'd like to give those routes names so when I create links to them from other pages I'll use some thing like:

```
link_to 'FAQ' faq_path'
```

rather then 
    link_to 'FAQ' '/pages/faq'

Is that possible to create "dynamic named routes"? I've tried things like:

```
match 'pages/:action' => 'pages#:action', :as => :action
```

but it didn't really work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't easily create dynamic methods like that, but if you think of it a different way you're actually parameterising your path helper. Rails *does* have an easy way to do this:

```
match "pages/:action", controller: "pages", as: "pages"

pages_path("faq") # => /pages/faq
```

Answer (score 1):

```
match "pages/faq", to: "pages#faq", as: "faq"
match "pages/home", to: "pages#home", as: "home"
match "pages/aboutus", to: "pages#aboutus", as: "aboutus"
```

would give you the following helpers:

```
home_path or home_url
faq_path or faq_url
aboutus_path or aboutus_url
```

Comment: That's far from being "dynamic named". And if you have dozens of those, you don't really want to list them all unless there is no other way.